# Dovecot expunge all emails marked as deleted regardless of folder

Tags: dovecot, imap

I would have thought that this would be a FAQ but I haven't found a useful answer.

How do I expunge all email messages deleted using the email client regardless of which folder it's in?

Comment: using [`doveadm`](https://wiki.dovecot.org/Tools/Doveadm/Expunge) this is easy. For a user this question is better suited for [su].

Comment: Thank you for coming back to me.  I did think that doveadm was the answer, although I could not find any reference to help with the search criteria. Thank you for pointing me to Super User. I will look at that

Comment: I restored the answer I wrote originally. I deleted it because I thought I misread your question.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick glance at [the manual](https://wiki.dovecot.org/Tools/Doveadm/Expunge), this should do it:

```
doveadm expunge ALL
```

This would affect all mailboxes.

To adapt an example from the [search-query manual](https://wiki.dovecot.org/Tools/Doveadm/SearchQuery):

```
doveadm expunge mailbox-guid 44f68b13ce97044b837f000035ca9452 ALL
```

This would only affect a single mailbox.

Comment: **Danger:** That search query does not include a filter for messages flagged as deleted yet.